# Data passing via model in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

I have the following code which works well using jquery-ajax call written. However i cannot figure out how to pass values via model. From some research i have done something and you can see it below(just above the ajax call).

I want to replace the $.ajax() with login.save() and pass values through the save(). Please let me know what i have done is correct or whether there is a better way of doing it. Can i write the success and failure callback inside model(as i have done)?

```
   //Login Page View
   var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el:"#main-content",
   initialize:function(){
          console.info("Login View Initialized");
          var template = _.template($('#login-template').html());
          this.$el.html(template);
   },
   render:function(){
          console.log("Login Render Function Called");
   },
   events:{
          'click #login':'login'
   },
   login:function(ev){      
          var loginDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();

          console.log(loginDetails);
          username = $("#username").val();  
          password = $("#password").val();
          ky         = 'MTWEB';

          if(username==""){
                 $('#username').css("border","1px solid #ff0000");
          }else if(password==""){
                 $('#password').css("border","1px solid #ff0000");
          }else{

                 var data = '{"un": "'+username+'","pd": "'+password+'","ky": "'+ky+'"}';
                 console.log(data);

                 //Using Backbone Model (I want to do it this way)
                 login.save({un : username,pd : password, ky : ky}, {
                                      success :function(){
                                      console.log("success");
                              },
                              error: function(){
                                      console.log("error");
                              }
                 });
                 //Using Backbone Model

          //jQuery Ajax Call (What i have done which works well)
          $.ajax({
                        url:basePath+'profile/Login',
                        data:data,
                        dataType:'json',
                        type:'POST',
                        success:function(result){
                                      $("#login_message #msg").html(result.me);
                                      $("#login_message").css('display','block');
                                      $("#login_message").removeClass('alert-success alert-error alert-warning');
                                      if(result.ss==1){
                                        $("#login_message").addClass('alert-success');
                                        console.log(result);
                                        return false;
                                      }else{
                                        $("#login_message").addClass('alert-error');
                                        console.info("Failed to Log In.");
                                      }
                                      return false;
                        },
                        error:function(result){
                                      console.log("fail :"+result);
                                      return false;
                        }
        });
        //jQuery Ajax Call

    }
    return false;
   }

   });

   var loginview = new LoginView();
```

Comment: very few backbone users i guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view doesn't look like it has a model

At the very least you need to do declare a model and pass it to the view when you create it. For example

```
var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend();

var loginview = new LoginView({ model: new LoginModel() });
```

Then in your view you need to call the save function on your model like:

```
this.model.save({un : username,pd : password, ky : ky}, {
                                  success :function(){
                                  console.log("success");
                          },
                          error: function(){
                                  console.log("error");
                          }
             });
```

At the moment its not clear what your login variable even is, but it doesn't look like a Backbone model.

Also keep in mind you'll have to pass the model a URL, so you probably should set it or pass it as a parameter upon instantiation like:

```
new LoginModel({}, { url: "/someurl"});
```

Comment: yeah i had declared login view and model separately. I thought i had to do it inside the extend() part.. thanks anyway.. works well..:)